# How can I return an array from a function in classic asp?

Tags: asp-classic

Tried this

```
Function myfunction()
Dim myArray(1)
myArray(0) = "1"
myArray(1) = "2"

myfunction = myArray
End Function

Dim newarray = myfunction()
```

And I get 500 error.

I'm using IIS7 with .NET runtime ASP.Net 2.0/3.0/3.5 On Godaddy's free economy hosting if that helps.

Comment: It confuses me when you refer to this as "classic asp" and then say you're using ASP.Net. There's a BIG difference. Which is it?

Comment: This is classic ASP. You can run classic asp on a server which is running ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBScript, you can't assign a value to a variable on the same line that you declare it.  You'll have to change

```
Dim newarray = myfunction()
```

to

```
Dim newarray
newarray = myfunction()
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can

```
Dim myVar : myVar = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What is also missing here is an example call to the function, which is important to illustrate, as it is at the calling code where another array has to be defined in the correct manner, as follows:

```
Dim aResultArray

aResultArray = MyFunction()

Response.Write("Value of aResultArray(0): ") & aResultArray(0) & "<br>"
Response.Write("Value of aResultArray(1): ") & aResultArray(1) & "<br>"
```

The array declaration is unique, in that it is defined as a standard variable so that it is similar to a pointer in memory, and since the return is an array, it is assigned to the variable as defined.  I have personally not seen an array return from an ASP classic function work properly in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

The array is being defined as ("1"), but you are trying to store 2 values in it.

Comment: Probably a good point. You should show your example in code. This to help future readers.

Comment: In VBScript, arrays are declared by specifying the upper boundary of the array in the declaration rather than the number of elements (and they are zero-based) so an array declared as (1) can hold 2 elements.